# Do multiclass Summoners still get to rearrange evolution points?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, summoner

If you are a Summoner and you dip into another class, do you still get to rearrange the evo points on the eidolon?

> The summoner can change them whenever he gains a level (and through the transmogrify spell).

As it doesn't specifically say "whenever he gains a summoner level", this looks to me like it should happen on any level up, but some clarification/rules examples would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No

From the *Summoner* [page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner#TOC-Eidolon):

> [evolution points] are set until he gains another level of summoner.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't see that. I was only looking at the Eidolons page.

Comment: @Wayne No worries. Happens to the best of us. It would be nice if Pathfinder had more consistent wording throughout their material.

Answer (score 0):

No it clearly states otherwise in the rules as written. "Whenever the summoner gains a level, he must decide how these points are spent, and they are set until he gains another level of summoner."  It's generally held to be a very bad idea  to take another class level as a Summoner.  Everything is based off your summoner level, and most of your cool advantages like casting spells with a range of self on your eidolon or wearing light armor only work with summoner spells.